# How to read special characters in Pyspark

Tags: csv, pyspark, unicode, encoding

Below special characters are present in a csv file.
" – " , " ’ " , " ‘ "
I am already using option("encoding","ISO-8859-1") in the read statement in order to handle few other scenarios (without this option few spaces are getting read as  – ).
But by using this option,
" Samsung – 22 " is getting read as " Samsung ? 22 "
"  ‘World’     " is getting read as "  ?World?  "

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].